# IKEA smastad cupboard pulls out at the bottom!

Tags: ikea

Ive attached a smastad cupboard to the wall using one of rails IKEA provide.

Inspite of all the screws being as tight as possible, I can slightly pull out the cupboard away from the wall (about 2cm) if I pull it at the bottom.

[image]

The rail is at the top as instructed. Is it normal to have this movement? I'm concerned because this cupboard is fitted above my daughter's bed!

[image]

Comment: The glyphs in the install instructions don’t make it obvious: can you lift the cabinet off the rails when it’s fully assembled, or would you have to unscrew something?

Comment: Does the IKEA instructions specifically say to hang it on the wall??? A lot of their furniture is not built for that, but they're all about tying it TO the wall to prevent topple, which has resulted in tragedy. Not the same as "hang from wall".   Is it tied into studs, and not just drywall?  Drywall is chalkboard chalk wrapped in paper.  That comparison actually disrespects chalkboard chalk.

Comment: I would not trust anything hanging from the wall, over the bed of my young child.

Comment: I think the OP is under the misconception that hanging the cabinet on the rail means that the bottom of the cabinet is fastened to the wall.  It's not.  If you're concerned about the bottom of the cabinet not being secured to the wall (true, a kid may yank on it or something), simply use a couple of long screws or bolts through the back panel of the cabinet into the wall, using suitable anchors, perhaps with a fender washer or something to help spread the load on the back panel.  AFAIK the rail doesn't prevent the cabinet from being lifted off the wall; this would prevent that too.

Comment: Its designed specifically to be attached to the wall on a rail without touching the floor.

I suspect Huesmann is correct.